# How to create a scope for records with highest value in associated table column

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have four related models:

```
class Quest < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :steps, -> { order(step_number: :asc) }
    def last_step_number
      steps.maximum(:step_number)
    end
end

class Step < ApplicationRecord
    validates :step_number, presence: true
    belongs_to :quest
end

class Teamquest < ApplicationRecord
    validates :last_step_completed, presence: true
    belongs_to :quest

    def is_all_steps_completed
      last_step_completed == quest.last_step_number
    end
end
```

I would like to add a scope to Teamquest that returns all records where Teamquest model method is_all_steps_completed == true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, a join with a select which returns only the row with the maximum step:

```
Teamquest.joins("
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT quest_id, MAX(step_number) AS max_step 
    FROM steps 
    GROUP BY quest_id) max_steps 
    ON max_steps.quest_id = teamquests.quest_id"
).where("last_step_completed = max_steps.max_step")
```

I would really consider denormalizing your database and storing `steps_count` in `quests` table to make everything easier.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly.  I attempted to create a scope on the Step model like this:  scope :last_steps, -> { select('quest_id, MAX(step_number) AS max_step').group(:quest_id) }    but I can't use it due to a postgres error PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "steps.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: How are you trying to use it? Using only the scope, as in `Step.last_steps` should work.

Comment: I was trying to use Step.last_steps.count and Step.last_steps.first -- neither of which worked.  I have since discovered that I can use Step.last_steps.each do ... which meets my needs perfectly.  Thanks!